# How actual parameter can be passed here?

Tags: javascript, php, scope

JS function can't be called with passed parameters

I've passed actual parameters from php file to divs with onclick event, it is rendered right on the page, function itself is present, but parameters aren't passed to function call

Formal argument stays like in function definition, it isn't substituted by what was passed to onclick events

http://localhost:8000/sknt1.php?reqStr

Code itself looks like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($json_a["tarifs"]) ; $i++) {
 echo "<div onclick='fun(".$i.")' class='column' style='font-size:20px; width:100%'>
```

On the page it looks like this (0 through 4):

```
<div onclick="fun(0)" class="column" style="font-size:20px; width:100%">
<div onclick="fun(1)" class="column" style="font-size:20px; width:100%">
```

And so on.

fun() is an AJAX call function, it is written to page one time, I cannot embed it in php for loop:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
function fun(reqStr) {
var xmlhttp = null;

function AjaxRequest(url){
  if(xmlhttp != null){
    if(xmlhttp.abort)
      xmlhttp.abort();
    xmlhttp = null;
  };
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // good browsers
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) // IE
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

  if(xmlhttp == null)
    return null;

  xmlhttp.open('GET',url,false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);

  if(xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300)// 2xx is good enough
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
  else
    return null;
}
window.history.replaceState({}, '',`/sknt1.php?reqStr`);
var url = '/sknt1.php?reqStr';
  var contents = AjaxRequest(url);
  if(contents){
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = contents;}
}
</script>
```

I want this Ajax call to substitute variable passed in and replace url for smth. like http://localhost:8000/sknt1.php?0, there's additional php file, it will render new page after manipulating the history, please help

Comment: What Ajax calls?

Comment: Do you see the output of your PHP in your JavaScript in the page source code? If so, the PHP portion of this is irrelevant and you should post *that* instead of this code.

Comment: Other people can not see your 'localhost' - post the code and results

Comment: Any feedback? I'm required to submit my code tomorrow, don't understand why actual parameters aren't substituted in general function. Any help would be highly appreciated, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a variable inside the for loop as $iStr = ' " '.$i.' " ' and pass the new variable.

Comment: It should be general function, only onclick calls inside for loop should vary

Answer (score 0):

It was a noob question. Obviously I should have concatenated arguments[0], not pass it directly.

Not this `/sknt1.php?reqStr`, but this `/sknt1.php?`+reqStr